# Toggle based on value in drop down

Tags: html

```html
<form>
  <p><strong>Would you like to receive the Stay Safe newsletter</strong>
    <select name="newsletter">
      <!-- dropdown box allows user to select if they want to receive newsletter-->
      <option value="yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="no">No</option>
    </select>
  </p>
  <p><textarea name="message" id="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea></p>
  <p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid email"></p>
  <button class="smallButton" type="submit">Send</button>
  <!-- submission button to send the form-->
</form>
```

I need help with coding my form what i want it to do is only show

```
<p><textarea name="message" id="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea></p> 
<p><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Valid email"></p>
<button class="smallButton" type="submit" >Send</button><!-- submission button to send the form-->
```

based on them selecting yes in the drop down box but unsure how to do this any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question is vague. On a sidenote, why not simply use a checkbox? It would greatly improve your UX design over a dropdown menu. (Since we're talking opt-in options for newsletters)

Comment: I created a snippet for you and formatted the code. Please take more care in explaining what you need with [mcve]

Comment: You need a script and wrap the stuff you want to toggle in a div: `<script>document.querySelector("[name=newsletter]").addEventListener("change",function() {  document.getElementById("addressDiv").classList.toggle("visibleClass",this.value=="yes") });</script>`

Answer (score 0):

I would use `onchange` and javascript to solve your question. Here is some [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp):

```
<select name="newsletter" onchange="newsletterChanged()">
```

then you can add javascript to hide or show the html you wish to:

```
function newsletterChanged() {
    //do work whenever newsletter changes.        
};
```

Hope this helps you on the way to solve your question. Happy coding :-)